# Basis for Quotient Ring of Group Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, group-rings

I recently read a paper from passman "*Observation On Group Rings*" and I came across a sentence below:

Let $H\lhd G$ and let $ B=\{B_1,B_2,B_3,...\}\subseteq K[H]$ be a $K-$basis for $w(K[H])^n/w(K[H])^{n+1}$.

Here, $K[H]$ denotes a group ring of group $H$ over field $K$, $w(K[H])$ denotes the augmentation ideal of $K[H]$ and $w(K[H])^n$ denotes the $n^{th}$ power of $w(K[H])$.

What I don't understand is why the basis of the quotient ring $w(K[H])^n/w(K[H])^{n+1}$ is a subset of $K[H]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a quotient ring; it's a quotient of ideals (so it forms a representation). Select coset representatives for each element of a basis of the quotient.

Comment: Did you mean that each element $B_i\in B$ is just a representation for the basis of the quotient? 
If yes, then shouldn't $B$ is just a subset of $w(K[H])^n$ instead of the whole $K[H]$? Thanks

Comment: @Andy yes, each $B_i$ is a representative, and yes, you are correct.